# How can I get java to tell me the correct amount of lines and words in a file?

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I am learning how to create a program that reads a file in class. I can only get java to tell me the correct amount of words in the file and not the correct amount of lines. How can I get java to tell me the correct amount of lines and words in a file?

public class Reader {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

```
BufferedReader demo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("All.txt"));

Scanner file = new Scanner(demo);

int lineCount = 0;
int wordCount = 0;
```

//wordCounter

```
while(file.hasNextLine()) {
  String amount = file.nextLine();

  String[] txt = amount.split(" ");
  for(int i = 0; i < txt.length; i++){
    if(txt[i].contains(txt[i]))
    wordCount++;
  }
}
System.out.println("There are  " + wordCount + " words.");
```

//lineCounter -- this is where my issue lies

```
String line = demo.readLine();
while(line != null){
  lineCount++;
  line = demo.readLine();

}
System.out.println("There are " + lineCount + " lines.");
```

}
}

Comment: What do you mean by line here?? A complete English sentence?? or when we encounter a return?

Comment: Why don't you count lines as soon as you read the line?  What is the purpose of check `if (txt[i].contains(txt[i]))` to count a word?

Comment: @asn21 I mean a complete sentence.

Comment: @AlexRudenko yes that is to the words

Comment: The problem is that ``txt[i].contains(txt[i])`` should always be true. A string always contains itself. What is this condition supposed to detect?

Comment: @Gia, this condition seems to be true _always_.  If you _mean_ to count _sentences_, then you should add more logic: 1) Process different  punctuation marks ending the sentence: `.`, '?', `!`  2) Handle cases: one line contains multiple sentences;  one sentence is spread across multiple lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

To count sentences split each line with either `.`, `!`, `?`.

To count words splitting with space will be enough.

```
import java.io.*;

public class File {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        BufferedReader demo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/asn/Desktop/All.txt"));
        
        int lineCount = 0;
        int wordCount = 0;
        String line;

        while((line=demo.readLine())!=null)  {
            String[] words = line.split(" ");
            String[] sen = line.split("\\.|\\!|\\?");  // this a a regex expression to split with ., !, and ?

            lineCount += sen.length;
            wordCount += words.length;
          }
          System.out.println("There are  " + wordCount + " words.");
          System.out.println("There are  " + lineCount + " lines.");

          demo.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the lines while counting words as shown below:

```
while(file.hasNextLine()) {
  lineCount++;// Add this line
  String amount = file.nextLine();
  String[] txt = amount.split(" ");
  wordCount += txt.length;// Add this line
}
System.out.println("There are  " + wordCount + " words.");
System.out.println("There are  " + lineCount + " lines.");// Add this line
```